# Angular get all form input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form" ng-submit="update(profile)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Facebook</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="profile.facebook"  class="form-control" placeholder="Facebook" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button ripple-button color="facebook" icon="facebook"></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Instagram</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="profile.instagram"  class="form-control" placeholder="Instagram" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button ripple-button color="instagram" icon="instagram"></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Controller:

```
Profile.get((resp)=>{
     $scope.profile = resp.result;
});

//resp.result is: {"id":"Hf561b6fd32aec6ea","name":"Example","nickname":"Example 1", "facebook":"example","instagram":"example"}

$scope.update = (profile) =>  {
    console.log(profile);
}
```

Here's the workflow: First all I will get profile from the server and put all ng-model `profile.*` value. And user can edit the value and submit.

The Problem: I want to get all value from the form at once. My ng-submit is working properly and it return profile value. 
My question is how can I only get the form key and value based on form instead of getting all the profile key?

my console.log return this:

```
{"id":"Hf561b6fd32aec6ea","name":"Example","nickname":"Example 1", "facebook":"thisischange","instagram":"thisischange"}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you are asking that you don't want key like id, name, nickname etc

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I just want value inside the form (facebook and instagram).

Comment: You can use jQuery `serializeArray` https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ you will need to convert it to object.

Comment: where is your id and nickname part in HTML?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers nope it's not. i just got that at my form

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using jQuery:

```
var object = {};
$('.form-horizontal').serializeArray().forEach(pair) {
    object[pair.name] = pair.value;
});
```